# How to get the index of the perticular clicked value in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading some card details on each of the td tag in table. When I click on particular td data, how to get the index of the perticular clicked value.

My table is.

```
    <table class="metricTable" border="2" bordercolor="white" 
           style="background-color:#066B12;">
    <tr>
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';"  >                                
                <input type="hidden" value="matches"/>
                <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
                <div class="card_content1" align="center"
                     style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div>
                <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                     style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                        
        </td>                                                                       
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';">
                <input type="hidden" value="runs"/>
                <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
                <div class="card_content1" align="center"
                    style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;">
                </div> 
                    <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                        style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;">
                </div>                              
        </td>                                                           
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';">                              
                <input type="hidden" value="centuries"/>
                <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
                <div class="card_content1" align="center" 
                    style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div> 
                <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                     style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';">                          
            <input type="hidden" value="fifties"/> 
            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <div class="card_content1" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div> 
            <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                        
        </td>                                                           
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';">                      
            <input type="hidden" value="batting_average"/>
            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <div class="card_content1" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div> 
            <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                    
        </td>                                                                       
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';">                      
            <input type="hidden" value="wickets"/>
            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <div class="card_content1" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div> 
            <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                                            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>                                        
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';">                      
            <input type="hidden" value="bowling_average"/>
            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <div class="card_content1" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div> 
            <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                                            
        </td>                                               
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';">                          
            <input type="hidden" value="best_bowling"/>
            <input type="hidden" value=""/>
            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <div class="card_content1" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;"></div> 
            <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                                                
        </td>                                                   
        <td class="metrics" onMouseover="this.bgColor='#4DBD33';" >
            <input type="hidden" value="catches"/>
            <input class="card_value" type="hidden" value=""/>
            <div class="card_content1" align="center" 
                 style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:150%;font-weight: bold;">
            </div> <div class="card_content" align="center" 
                       style="color:#FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;"></div>                 
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

hi I have one problem how to get this value please. Intially I loaded the cards to table by this way, the user card is `var userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['user_Card']);` is taken from loacal storgae

and it loaded to table by this way `$(this).find('.card_value').val(userCard[0][4]);`

I want to get this (`userCard[0][4]`) for compare purpose, how to get this value ?

**how to get the index for the perticular clicked td tag ?**

Comment: hi i have one problem how to get this value please, intially i loaded the cards to table by this way, the user card is var userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['user_Card']); is taken from loacal storgae. and it loaded to table by this way $(this).find('.card_value').val(userCard[0][4]); i want to get this (userCard[0][4]) for compare purpose, how to get this value..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `index()` function, but this gives you index with respect to all its siblings.

```
$("td").click(function(){
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

Example : suppose there are 5 `td`s inside `tr` and you clicked 2nd td then its index will be 1 (as index is zero based)

But for other tr, if you click 2nd td then it should give you 1 as these index are with respect to all siblings and not global.

to find card value like userCard[0][4],  use below code

```
$("td").click(function(){
      var card_val = $(this).find('.card_value').val();
      alert(card_val );
    });
```

Comment: hi i have one problem how to get this value please, intially i loaded the cards to table by this way, the user card is var userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['user_Card']); is taken from loacal storgae. and it loaded to table by this way $(this).find('.card_value').val(userCard[0][4]); i want to get this (userCard[0][4]) for compare purpose, how to get this value..

Comment: userCard[0][4] is first tr and 4th td OR first tr and 5th td?

Comment: userCard[0][4] zero means the first card, 4th means 4th element in the firstcard.

Comment: pls see my updated answer, this will give you card_value for clicked td

Comment: i also getting the card value userCard[0][4], but i want to get the index of the card_value as 4 for comparing purpose by programmatically.

Comment: then do var cardIndex = $(this).index()+1; add 1 because our index is zero based OR you can use regEx to find numbers and then read last number i.e. 4 in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use ***`.index()`*** in jquery

```
$(".metricTable").on("click" , "td.metrics" , function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: hi i have one problem how to get this value please, intially i loaded the cards to table by this way, the user card is var userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['user_Card']); is taken from loacal storgae. and it loaded to table by this way $(this).find('.card_value').val(userCard[0][4]); i want to get this (userCard[0][4]) for compare purpose, how to get this value..